# Could not open input file: composer

Tags: php, laravel, facade

I am trying to pull in a [shopping cart facade](https://cartalyst.com/manual/cart/2.0#setup) to my Laravel application. Upon pulling in the Facade vis composer, I get the following error:

> Could not open input file: composer

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I've tried several shopI don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I've tried several facades and they all seem to screw up when I try to bring them in via composer.Any help?

Comment: What are you typing to bring them in with composer?

Comment: php composer instaIl, as the manual says. here's my error message: php composer update
Could not open input file: composer

Comment: This happens because php can't find the file.  Are you in the right directory and if so, are you sure it's `composer` and not `composer.phar`?  It might also help to install composer globally so all you need to do is `composer install`

Comment: I have composer globally installed on my machine. I tried running composer from Mint Linux's built in CLI and I get output saying the repo could not be downloaded from GitHub.

Comment: I have made a few changes to my app.php file. Now I'm getting the following output on composer install:                                                                               
  [RuntimeException]                                                           
  Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundat  
  ion\Application::bindShared() in /home/thomas/ushop/vendor/illuminate/html/  
  HtmlServiceProvider.php on line 36