# InvalidArgumentException with composer.phar at Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, composer-php

I need your help, please. At https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/installation.html#step-1-download-craft I have this instruction: "To create a new Craft project, run this command (substituting  with the path where Composer should create the project): composer create-project craftcms/craft  "

I get " [InvalidArgumentException] .Could not find package craftcms/users/lestone2 with stability stable", on entering "composer create-project craftcms/Users/lestone2".
I get the same message on entering "php composer.phar create-project craftcms/Users/lestone2"
Can someone help me to set up the instruction correctly? Or do I have a permissions issue? (I am logged on as the admin.).
I found one related question at: [Could not open input file: composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897084/could-not-open-input-file-composer) ; but the issue there is not the same as mine.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of the `create-project` command must be the name of a package. If you want to customise the directory where your project is created, you need to pass it as the second argument like this:

```
composer create-project craftcms/craft craftcms/users/lestone2
```